# want it to be trim my TCHAR * from end only

Tags: c++, mfc

```
TCHAR* pszBackupPath;

m_Edt_ExportPath.GetWindowText(pszBackupPath, dwcchBackupPath);
StrTrim(pszBackupPath, L" ");
StrTrim(pszBackupPath, L"\\");    //this line has issue

iRet = _tcslen(pszBackupPath);
boRet = PathIsNetworkPath(pszBackupPath);
if (FALSE == boRet)
{
//  MessageBox with string "Entered path is network path.
}   
boRet = PathIsDirectory(pszBackupPath);
if (FALSE == boRet)
{
//  MessageBox with string "Entered path is not a valid directory.
}
```

This is a part of my code in MFC.
I am passing a network path from UI. But because of StrTrim(pszBackupPath, L"\\") "\\" get trimmed from start and end. But I want it to be trimmed from end only.
I don't know any direct API. Please suggest.

Comment: Where do you initialize `pszBackupPath`?  Your code declares a pointer, and then you pass this uninitialized pointer to `GetWindowText`.  That isn't going to work, and I'm surprised the code didn't crash.  A `TCHAR*` is not a string -- it is a single pointer and it needs to point to a buffer first before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple function to do that: [PathRemoveBackslash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773743.aspx) (or [PathCchRemoveBackslash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707089.aspx) for Windows 8 and later).